# Average vertex degree in finite Delaunay triangulations in high dimensions

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's known that with a "random" point configuration, the average degree of a vertex in its Delaunay triangulation is 6.

Does anyone know of a similar result in higher dimension? I am particularly interested in the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good survey (of experimental and theoretical results) in [Tanemura's 2003 paper.](http://wildfire.stat.ucla.edu/pdflibrary/tanemura.pdf)

Comment: The link is broken. You might want to update it to this link: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.613.7245&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3):

Let me point out a very significant difference between dimensions 2 and 3. In dimension 2 ANY triangulation (Delaunay or not, random or not) has average degree strictly smaller than six (and going to six as the ratio "boundary points / interior points" goes to zero). This is a consequence of Euler's formula.

In dimension three, however, there are triangulations (even Delaunay triangulations) with arbitrarily many points and a complete graph, that is, with average degree $n-1$ where $n$ is the number of points. What this means, in particular, is that the answer to the question may depend in how you sample.

Going to a very degenerate situation, [Amenta et al](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~amenta/pubs/HiDeeDel.pdf) studied what happens when you sample uniformly on a (perhaps lower dimensional) polyhedron.